# How to set relational attributes on new model with Backbone-relational

Tags: rest, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am building a JavaScript app, and have been learning JavaScript and Backbone, and have added Backbone-relational to it. It saves to a Django-tastypie REST server.

So before I was using Backbone-relational, I would create a new object, and either set the attributes when it was created, by passing them to the constructor, or passing a dictionary of attributes to the `save()` method.

e.g in CoffeeScript:

```
myModel.save {attribute:value  , foreignKey_attribute : '/api/resourceUri/'}
    success -> 
        ....
```

Now I have switched to Backbone-relational, it solves a lot of problems fetching the data, but I cant seem to set the foreign key attribute as before.

Either passing the dictionary to the constructor, or the save method. When I look at the object in the console, or the contents of the POST, the `foreign_key` attribute is always `null`.

Is there a way around this, or another way of setting the `foreign_key_attribute` (given that I have the foreign key id)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked it out.

Rather than trying to set the flowcell to a resource_uri string, set it as the flowcell object.

Then in the relations I needed to set the following:

```
includeInJSON: 'resource_uri'
```

This serialzes the object the way the tastypie back end expects it.